# Insert a blank row after each group of data

Tags: r

This question has been asked for excel. [How to automatically insert a blank row after a group of data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15417544/2862090)

I would like to know if there is a function for doing the same in R.

example:

```
group <- c("a","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","d")
xvalue <- c(16:25)
yvalue <- c(1:10)
df <- data.frame(cbind(group,xvalue,yvalue))
   group xvalue yvalue
1      a     16      1
2      b     17      2
3      b     18      3
4      c     19      4
5      c     20      5
6      c     21      6
7      d     22      7
8      d     23      8
9      d     24      9
10     d     25     10
```

I would like to have a blank row after each group so that I can check the entries manually

```
   group xvalue yvalue
1      a     16      1
2
3      b     17      2
4      b     18      3
5
6      c     19      4
7      c     20      5
8      c     21      6
9
10     d     22      7
11     d     23      8
12     d     24      9
12     d     25     10
```

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First transform all columns to character vectors:

```
df_new <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then you can create the output you're looking for:

```
head(do.call(rbind, by(df_new, df$group, rbind, "")), -1 )

#      group xvalue yvalue
# a.1      a     16      1
# a.2                     
# b.2      b     17      2
# b.3      b     18      3
# b.31                    
# c.4      c     19      4
# c.5      c     20      5
# c.6      c     21      6
# c.41                    
# d.7      d     22      7
# d.8      d     23      8
# d.9      d     24      9
# d.10     d     25     10
```

Comment: @ sven: why transform all variables to text? Also could make a solution with tidyverse?

Comment: @David How do you want to represent "empty rows" without text?

Comment: @ sven. Sorry for late reply. For every group I would like to insert a blank row and fill the values with e.g, an average of the group.

Comment: @David Of course, you insert values into the "blank" rows, but this is not the solution the OP was looking for.

Comment: @ svend. Okay... I have a new question about encoding, could you look at it? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764918/encoding-problem-correct-special-characters-after-reading-in-the-table)

Answer (score 7):

Sven has answered exactly what you've asked for, but I think what you want to do is a generally bad idea.

If visual separation is all that you are hoping to achieve, I would recommend just using `split`:

```
split(df, df$group)
# $a
#   group xvalue yvalue
# 1     a     16      1
#
# $b
#   group xvalue yvalue
# 2     b     17      2
# 3     b     18      3
#
# $c
#   group xvalue yvalue
# 4     c     19      4
# 5     c     20      5
# 6     c     21      6
#
# $d
#    group xvalue yvalue
# 7      d     22      7
# 8      d     23      8
# 9      d     24      9
# 10     d     25     10
```

This has the advantages of (1) visual separation, (2) easy indexing, (3) no conversion of your data, and (4) allowing you to run the same functions on different subsets of your data.

Comment: @Anando I agree with you and thank you for telling me about `split` function. In this case I have more than 500 groups and need to manually inspect each one against the original print document. The choice is to export to excel and then run the excel macro to split or  split in r and export to excel.