# Inserting rows before each group

Tags: r

i have the following list and I would want to add a new row before each group of ID's preserving the ID and setting the A and B to 1.00.

```
       ID      DATEE       A      B 
   102984 2016-11-23      2.0    2.0
   140349 2016-11-23      1.5    1.5
   167109 2017-04-16      2.0    2.0
   167109 2017-06-21      1.5    1.5
```

The end result:

```
  ID      DATEE           A      B     
  102984    NA           1.0    1.0
  102984 2016-11-23      2.0    2.0       
  140349    NA           1.0    1.0      
  140349 2016-11-23      1.5    1.5
  167109    NA           1.0    1.0             
  167109 2017-04-16      2.0    2.0       
  167109 2017-06-21      1.5    1.5
```

Up until now I used the following code which adds an empty row at the bottom of each group do.call(rbind, by(df,df$ID,rbind,"")) however I couldn't introduce the specific values in their respective columns when I substituted "" by a vector of values.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/27730389/ and maybe consider eddi's comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652533/insert-a-row-in-a-data-table#comment23954008_16652533

Answer (score 7):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  We get the `distinct` rows of dataset by 'ID', `mutate` the variables 'A', 'B' to 1, and 'DATEE' to NA, then with `bind_rows` row bind with the original dataset and `arrange` by 'ID'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all= TRUE) %>%
  mutate_at(vars("A", "B"), funs((1))) %>% 
  mutate(DATEE = NA) %>%
  bind_rows(., df1) %>%
  arrange(ID)
#     ID      DATEE   A   B
#1 102984       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#2 102984 2016-11-23 2.0 2.0
#3 140349       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#4 140349 2016-11-23 1.5 1.5
#5 167109       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#6 167109 2017-04-16 2.0 2.0
#7 167109 2017-06-21 1.5 1.5
```

(I'll assume the date formatting has been fixed, e.g., with `df1$DATEE = as.Date(df1$DATEE)`.)

---

Or translated to base R:

```
new1 = data.frame(ID = unique(df1$ID), DATEE = Sys.Date()[NA_integer_], A = 1, B = 1)
tabs = list(new1, df1)
res  = do.call(rbind, tabs)
res <- res[order(res$ID), ]

#       ID      DATEE   A   B
# 1 102984       <NA> 1.0 1.0
# 4 102984 2016-11-23 2.0 2.0
# 2 140349       <NA> 1.0 1.0
# 5 140349 2016-11-23 1.5 1.5
# 3 167109       <NA> 1.0 1.0
# 6 167109 2017-04-16 2.0 2.0
# 7 167109 2017-06-21 1.5 1.5
```

---

Or with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
new1 = data.table(ID = unique(df1$ID), DATEE = Sys.Date()[NA_integer_], A = 1, B = 1)
tabs = list(new1, df1)
res  = rbindlist(tabs)
setorder(res)

#       ID      DATEE   A   B
#1: 102984       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#2: 102984 2016-11-23 2.0 2.0
#3: 140349       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#4: 140349 2016-11-23 1.5 1.5
#5: 167109       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#6: 167109 2017-04-16 2.0 2.0
#7: 167109 2017-06-21 1.5 1.5
```

There are some other ways, too:

```
# or let DATEE and other cols be filled as NA
library(data.table)
new1 = data.table(ID = unique(df1$ID), A = 1, B = 1)
tabs = list(df1, new1)
res  = rbindlist(tabs, fill = TRUE, idcol = "src")
setorder(res, ID, -src)
res[, src := NULL ]

# or a more compact option (assuming df1$A has no missing values)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[c(.N+1, seq_len(.N))], ID][is.na(A), c("A", "B") := 1][]
```

Comment: @Frank Thank you for the update.  I was in a call, so couldn't check this

Answer (score 4):

Here are two solutions with base R

## 1

Split into sub-groups based on `ID`, add a row to the top of each sub-group, and `rbind` everything back at the end.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(a){
    rbind(setNames(c(a$ID[1], NA, 1, 1), names(a)), a)
}))
#             ID      DATEE   A   B
#102984.1 102984       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#102984.2 102984 2016-11-23 2.0 2.0
#140349.1 140349       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#140349.2 140349 2016-11-23 1.5 1.5
#167109.1 167109       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#167109.3 167109 2017-04-16 2.0 2.0
#167109.4 167109 2017-06-21 1.5 1.5
```

## 2

Or you could initially replicate the first rows (by identifying them with ave) and then substitute appropriate values in each column.

```
df = df[sort(c(1:NROW(df), which(ave(df$A, df$ID, FUN = seq_along) == 1))),]
df$DATEE = replace(df$DATEE, which(ave(df$A, df$ID, FUN = seq_along) == 1), NA)
df$A = replace(df$A, which(ave(df$A, df$ID, FUN = seq_along) == 1), 1)
df$B = replace(df$B, which(ave(df$A, df$ID, FUN = seq_along) == 1), 1)
df
#        ID      DATEE   A   B
#1   102984       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#1.1 102984 2016-11-23 2.0 2.0
#2   140349       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#2.1 140349 2016-11-23 1.5 1.5
#3   167109       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#3.1 167109 2017-04-16 2.0 2.0
#4   167109 2017-06-21 1.5 1.5
```

Answer (score 4):

Another idea using `purrr`. First, we `split()` the data by `ID`, then we use `imap` (indexed map) with `dfr` (return data frames created by row-binding) to loop over each group and `add_row()` with the specified values.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  split(.$ID) %>%
  # We don't have to specify "DATEE", absent variables get missing values
  imap_dfr(~ add_row(.x, ID = .y, A = 1, B = 1, .before = 1))
```

Which gives:

```
#      ID      DATEE   A   B
#1 102984       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#2 102984 2016-11-23 2.0 2.0
#3 140349       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#4 140349 2016-11-23 1.5 1.5
#5 167109       <NA> 1.0 1.0
#6 167109 2017-04-16 2.0 2.0
#7 167109 2017-06-21 1.5 1.5
```

---

From the documentation:

> `imap_xxx(x, ...)`, an indexed map, is short hand for `map2(x, names(x),
>   ...)` if `x` has names, or `map2(x, seq_along(x), ...)` if it does not.
>   This is useful if you need to compute on both the value and the
>   position of an element.

Answer (score 3):

Find the indexes of non-duplicates, `u`, and then repeat those rows giving `DF2`.  Then find the non-duplicates, `uu`, in `DF2` and insert NA, 1, 1 into those rows except for first column.  No packages are used.

```
u <- !duplicated(DF$ID)
DF2 <- DF[rep(1:nrow(DF), 1 + u), ]
uu <- !duplicated(DF2$ID)
DF2[uu, -1] <- list(NA, 1, 1)
```

giving:

```
> DF2
        ID      DATEE   A   B
1   102984       <NA> 1.0 1.0
1.1 102984 2016-11-23 2.0 2.0
2   140349       <NA> 1.0 1.0
2.1 140349 2016-11-23 1.5 1.5
3   167109       <NA> 1.0 1.0
3.1 167109 2017-04-16 2.0 2.0
4   167109 2017-06-21 1.5 1.5
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
     ID      DATEE       A      B 
   102984 2016-11-23      2.0    2.0
   140349 2016-11-23      1.5    1.5
   167109 2017-04-16      2.0    2.0
   167109 2017-06-21      1.5    1.5"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

**Updates:** Have corrected output (code was correct but output did not correspond) and also simplified code.

Answer (score 2):

Joining this party, here is yet another base R solution. We replicate row names in order to expand our data frame, and then simply replace the values

```
d1 <- df[rep(rownames(df), (!duplicated(df$ID)) + 1),]
d1$DATEE <- replace(d1$DATEE, !duplicated(d1$ID), NA)
d1[-c(1:2)] <- lapply(d1[-c(1:2)], function(i) replace(i, is.na(d1$DATEE), 1))
```

Which gives,

> ```
>        ID      DATEE   A   B
> 1   102984       <NA> 1.0 1.0
> 1.1 102984 2016-11-23 2.0 2.0
> 2   140349       <NA> 1.0 1.0
> 2.1 140349 2016-11-23 1.5 1.5
> 3   167109       <NA> 1.0 1.0
> 3.1 167109 2017-04-16 2.0 2.0
> 4   167109 2017-06-21 1.5 1.5
> ```

Comment: Last line depends on there being no legit NAs in the original table?

Comment: @Frank not the original. The one where I updated `DATEE`

Comment: Not sure I follow. I meant that with `df = data.frame(ID = 1, DATEE = Sys.Date()[NA_integer_], A = 2, B = 3)`, you'll overwrite my values for A and B since the original date is NA...?

Comment: @Frank oh ok, I got you. I m not sure how it will behave. I will update with the `duplicated` condition just to be sure

Answer (score 2):

we can also use the `by` function you wanted to use or even `tapply` function in base R. for `tapply` ensure to put the `INDICES` in a list since this is a data frame. Foe `by` it is not necessary to put it in a list. So in the code below, we can replace `by(A,A$ID...` with `tapply(A,list(A$ID)...` and both will give the same results.

```
`rownames<-`(do.call(rbind,by(A,A$ID,
                  function(i) rbind(data.frame(ID=i$ID[1],DATEE=NA,A=1,B=1),i))),NULL)
      ID      DATEE   A   B
1 102984       <NA> 1.0 1.0
2 102984 2016-11-23 2.0 2.0
3 140349       <NA> 1.0 1.0
4 140349 2016-11-23 1.5 1.5
5 167109       <NA> 1.0 1.0
6 167109 2017-04-16 2.0 2.0
7 167109 2017-06-21 1.5 1.5
```

No sorting is needed for this, since that may distort the order that the data was at previously.

Comment: The `rownames<-` might be hard for some folks to follow. Maybe worth showing the verbose / two-line way with `res <- do.call...; rownames(res) <- NULL`.

Comment: You are right. Though It is good to learn a new trick in R too. And also it should be  `(rownames(res) <-NULL)` for you to be able to view the results at the same time.

Comment: I think you can use the argument of rbind,  `make.row.names = FALSE`... So maybe `do.call(rbind, c(by(...), make.row.names = FALSE)` but I m not sure. You can check