# Intercalate NAs with data in new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a `df` like this:

```
           X1  X2  X3  X4
Number      4   4   4   4
Number.1    2   3   3   2
```

And I'd like to transform it into this:

```
> X1
  NA
   4
   2
  NA
   4
   3
  NA
   4
   3
  NA
   4
   2
  NA
```

How can I intercalate `NA` with my `df` like in the example?
So far I tried with `sapply(df, function(x) NA, t(Number(y)))` but it retrieves an error... I know I have to use `t()` to transpose my `df` but how to add the `NA` in between columns to rows?

Any suggestions?

**Note:** I am not new to `R` but lately I have been having some issues... I searched all over StackOverflow but I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea via `stack`ing the data frame and using `ind` and our group indicator to add the extra rows, i.e.

```
s_df <- stack(df)
rbind(data.frame(values = NA, ind = NA), do.call(rbind, by(s_df, s_df$ind, rbind, NA)))[1]
```

which gives,

> ```
>       values
> 1         NA
> X1.1       4
> X1.2       2
> X1.3      NA
> X2.3       4
> X2.4       3
> X2.31     NA
> X3.5       4
> X3.6       3
> X3.3      NA
> X4.7       4
> X4.8       2
> X4.3      NA
> ```

**DISCLAIMER** Credits go to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20260617/5635580)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rbind(NA, dat)` and `unlist` with `use.name = FALSE` - thanks to @zx8754.

```
data.frame(X1 = c(unlist(rbind(NA, dat), use.name = FALSE), NA))
```

Result

```
#   X1
#1  NA
#2   4
#3   2
#4  NA
#5   4
#6   3
#7  NA
#8   4
#9   3
#10 NA
#11  4
#12  2
#13 NA
```

`c(..., NA)` appends `NA` at the end of the vector.

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(X1 = c(4L, 2L), X2 = c(4L, 3L), X3 = c(4L, 3L), 
    X4 = c(4L, 2L)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Number", 
"Number.1"))
```

Comment: Or `unlist(..., use.name = FALSE)` instead of `unname()`.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting out of range rows creates `NA` rows, then `unlist`:

```
data.frame(X1 = c(NA, unlist(dat[1:3, ], use.names = FALSE)))
#    X1
# 1  NA
# 2   4
# 3   2
# 4  NA
# 5   4
# 6   3
# 7  NA
# 8   4
# 9   3
# 10 NA
# 11  4
# 12  2
# 13 NA
```