# Insert blank row between groups and maintain original order

Tags: r

I'm basically doing what is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260458/insert-a-blank-row-after-each-group-of-data), however I'm trying to maintain the original order of the `month` column. A roundabout way would be to add a leading zero to the single digit numbers. I'm trying to find a way without doing that.

Current code:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- structure(list(parameters = c("temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp", "temp"), month = c("2", "2", "2", "5", "5", "5", "8", "8", "8", "11", "11", "11", "annual", "annual", "annual")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
do.call(bind_rows, by(df, df[ ,c("month", "parameters")], rbind, ""))
```

The `by` function looks like it coerces your defined indices to factors, and converting `month` to a factor reveals that it makes the levels in that order: `11, 2, 5, 8, annual`. If it were numeric, it would order them correctly, but with `annual` included, that column must be as a character.

If I convert it to a factor first, and order the levels, my code will insert `NA`s.

```
df$month <- ordered(df$month, levels = c("2", "5", "8", "11", "annual"))
do.call(bind_rows, by(df, df[ ,c("month", "parameters")], rbind, ""))
```

Current output:

```
   parameters  month
1        temp     11
2        temp     11
3        temp     11
4                   
5        temp      2
6        temp      2
7        temp      2
8                   
9        temp      5
10       temp      5
11       temp      5
12                  
13       temp      8
14       temp      8
15       temp      8
16                  
17       temp annual
18       temp annual
19       temp annual
20
```

Desired output:

```
   parameters month
1        temp     2
2        temp     2
3        temp     2
4                  
5        temp     5
6        temp     5
7        temp     5
8                  
9        temp     8
10       temp     8
11       temp     8
12                 
13       temp    11
14       temp    11
15       temp    11
16                 
17       temp annual
18       temp annual
19       temp annual
20
```

Comment: It is because you don't have `""` as levels.  Add that in the `ordered` and it would be fine

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks @akrun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that after the column 'month' got changed to an `ordered` factor, `""` is not specified as one of the `levels`.  So, naturally any value that is not a `level` is treated as missing value and hence we get the `NA`.  Correction can be done at the earlier step by including the `""` as one of the `levels`

```
df$month <- ordered(df$month, levels = c("2", "5", "8", "11", "annual", ""))
```

NOTE: The `order` of the `""` is not clear.  So, it is specified as the last `level`

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative approach, which uses [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)'s incarnation of the `rbind()` function to append a blank line after each group:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, rbind(.SD, data.table(parameters = "")), by = month]
```

> ```
>      month parameters
>  1:      2       temp
>  2:      2       temp
>  3:      2       temp
>  4:      2           
>  5:      5       temp
>  6:      5       temp
>  7:      5       temp
>  8:      5           
>  9:      8       temp
> 10:      8       temp
> 11:      8       temp
> 12:      8           
> 13:     11       temp
> 14:     11       temp
> 15:     11       temp
> 16:     11           
> 17: annual       temp
> 18: annual       temp
> 19: annual       temp
> 20: annual
> ```

The order of groups is kept. The grouping variable `month` appears in front of each line. This approach can also be used to intersperse an arbitrary number of blank lines if required:

```
n_blank <- 2L
setDT(df)[, rbind(.SD, data.table(parameters = rep("", n_blank))), by = month]
```

> ```
>      month parameters
>  1:      2       temp
>  2:      2       temp
>  3:      2       temp
>  4:      2           
>  5:      2           
>  6:      5       temp
>  7:      5       temp
>  8:      5       temp
>  9:      5           
> 10:      5           
> 11:      8       temp
> 12:      8       temp
> 13:      8       temp
> 14:      8           
> 15:      8           
> 16:     11       temp
> 17:     11       temp
> 18:     11       temp
> 19:     11           
> 20:     11           
> 21: annual       temp
> 22: annual       temp
> 23: annual       temp
> 24: annual           
> 25: annual           
>      month parameters
> ```