# How to write insert new row after values do not repeat each other VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with numbers like:

```
66234 
666575 
66567 
665687 
66090 
66000
```

And I need to write code that detects when "77" + SomeNumber starts. And insert empty row between new numbers.

What command I should use?

Comment: Range("").EntireRow.Insert

Comment: `Rows(x).Insert Shift:=xlDown` where `x` is the row number.  Could you clarify this line: **"detects when 77 + SomeNumber starts"**

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417544/how-to-automatically-insert-a-blank-row-after-a-group-of-data  /// just use Left(Cells(iRow + 1, iCol), 2) <> Left(Cells(iRow, iCol), 2) instead original

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
Sub InsertRow()

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To n
    If Left(Cells(i, 1), 2) = 77 Then
        Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

replace the 1 in `n=...` with the column that has the main numbers in
replace the `cells(i,1)` and `for i =1` with the respective rows to begin at :)

Comment: Did this help you?