# Insert Blank Row In Python Data frame when value in column changes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I'd like to insert a blank row as a separator whenever the value in the first column changes.

For example:

```
Column 1     Col2    Col3    Col4
A            s       b       d
A            s       j       k
A            b       d       q
B            b       a       d
C            l       k       p
```

becomes:

```
Column 1     Col2    Col3    Col4
A            s       b       d
A            s       j       k
A            b       d       q

B            b       a       d

C            l       k       p
```

because the value in Column 1 changed

The only way that I figured out how to do this is using VBA as indicated by the correctly marked answer here:

[How to automatically insert a blank row after a group of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417544/how-to-automatically-insert-a-blank-row-after-a-group-of-data)

But I need to do this in Python.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create helper `DataFrame` with index values of last changes, add `.5`, join together with original by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), sorting indices by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), create default index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and lasr remove last row by positions with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
mask = df['Column 1'].ne(df['Column 1'].shift(-1))
df1 = pd.DataFrame('',index=mask.index[mask] + .5, columns=df.columns)

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:-1]
print (df)
  Column 1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0        A    s    b    d
1        A    s    j    k
2        A    b    d    q
3                        
4        B    b    a    d
5                        
6        C    l    k    p
```

Comment: This works beautifully, though one caveat is that if your data frame is in sorted order already, you will want to do a df = df.reset_index(drop=True) before the mask line if you don't already have that in your code. Otherwise the frame will be resorted on indices, rather than whatever criteria you used previously.