# Pandas: read rows from an excel file and write them to another one

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hi I'm pretty new to python and I'm trying to use pandas as described in the title.
My problem is very simple but I'm having some trouble with it: I need to read some rows from an excel file and, if the row's first column value it's not equal to the next row's first column value, I have to insert an empty row in the excel.
In order to do this I would like to read a row from my original excel, compare his value with the next one and, if they are the equal, write them in the other excel file. If they are different, I want to write an empty row, and then the different value row.

thanks in advance!

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: There's an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105398/insert-blank-row-in-python-data-frame-when-value-in-column-changes)