# Inserting blank line in dataframe when data change

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to insert a blank line into a dataframe whenever a value changes. However my loop accumulate an extra step each time it runs and I can't figure out why.

```
import pandas as pd

# The blank row to insert
blank_row = [None, None]

#The first order number
first_order_number = df.iloc[0, 0]

# Loops over the df and if a new order number, insert the row. 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Purchase order'] != first_order_number:
        last_df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(last_df.values, index, blank_row,
                                         axis=0), columns=last_df.columns)
        # Set order variable to the new
        first_order_number = row['Purchase order']
```

Input data:

```
Purchase order  Store
795571          4
795571          4
795562          5
795562          5
795562          5 
795586          9
795586          9
795586          9
795588          10
795588          10
795588          10
795588          10
```

Expected output:

```
Purchase order  Store
795571          4
795571          4

795562          5
795562          5
795562          5 

795586          9
795586          9
795586          9

795588          10
795588          10
795588          10
795588          10
```

Output:

```
Purchase order  Store 
795571          4
795571          4

795562          5
795562          5

795562          5 
795586          9

795586          9
795586          9
795588          10

795588          10
795588          10
795588          10
```

My best guess is that when the variable first_order_number gets updated it looks at the current index and inserts the value at ['Purchase order'] this step then turns to two next time around. To fix this I changed it to:

```
first_order_number = df.iloc[index + 1, 0]
```

This just put the counter out of sync and filled up with None-rows after store 5.
How can I fix this?

Maybe there is also a better way to achieve this since I know loops over DFs are slow.

Many thanks for all input

Comment: Can you provide input data in text sample?

Comment: Added input data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert Blank Row In Python Data frame when value in column changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105398/insert-blank-row-in-python-data-frame-when-value-in-column-changes)

Comment: @norie It looks like a short and sweet solution but I can't get it to work. When I try the solution I end up with a blank line after each row. Maybe I'm missing something, I don't fully understand what's happening in your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54105450/5660315, first
calculate the last row for each purchase order in `mask`. Then assign
intermediate index values for purchase order changes in `df1`.
Finally, add these new index rows to `df`, resetting the index, and
dropping the last empty line.

```
# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/54105450/5660315
# Insert empty line after change in first column value

from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data_text ="""
Purchase order,Store
795571,4
795571,4
795562,5
795562,5
795562,5 
795586,9
795586,9
795586,9
795588,10
795588,10
795588,10
795588,10
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_text))
mask = df['Purchase order'].ne(df['Purchase order'].shift(-1))
df1 = pd.DataFrame('',index=mask.index[mask] + .5, columns=df.columns)

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:-1]
print(df.to_string(index=False))
# Purchase order Store
#         795571     4
#         795571     4
                    
#         795562     5
#         795562     5
#         795562     5
                    
#         795586     9
#         795586     9
#         795586     9
                    
#         795588    10
#         795588    10
#         795588    10
#         795588    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')

blank_row=[np.nan, np.nan]

l = []

for n,g in df.groupby('Purchase order'):
    l.append(g)
    l.append(pd.DataFrame([blank_row], columns=df.columns, index=[0]))

df_out = pd.concat(l,ignore_index=True).iloc[:-1]
df_out
```

Output:

```
   Purchase order  Store
0         795562.0    5.0
1         795562.0    5.0
2         795562.0    5.0
3              NaN    NaN
4         795571.0    4.0
5         795571.0    4.0
6              NaN    NaN
7         795586.0    9.0
8         795586.0    9.0
9         795586.0    9.0
10             NaN    NaN
11        795588.0   10.0
12        795588.0   10.0
13        795588.0   10.0
14        795588.0   10.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out! Are the "Store" and "Purchase order" converted to floats by the numpy operation? How do I combat this?

Comment: Unfortunate side effect of pandas for columns with NaN.  However, we can use a new Pandas dtype to combat this.

Answer (score 0):

What is the criteria of grouping certain rows and separating the groups with the blank line?
EDIT: Heyy!!
USE THIS :

```
data[2] = data.duplicated(subset=0)
for index in data.loc[data[2] == False].index - 1:
    data.loc[index] = ' '
```

replace 'data' with your DataFrame's name

Thanks !

Comment: It should be grouped by column 'Purchase order'. Whenever that value is not the same as the value above it should insert a blank line

Comment: Alright, I am doing it. Will get it back to you once i am done

Comment: I have edited my previous post with the code. Do try it and give feedbaakc, Thanks