# Insert 2 Blank Rows In DF by Group

Tags: python, pandas

I basically want the solution from this question to be applied to 2 blank rows.

[Insert Blank Row In Python Data frame when value in column changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105398/insert-blank-row-in-python-data-frame-when-value-in-column-changes)

I've messed around with the solution but don't understand the code enough to alter it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
num_empty_rows = 2
df = (df.groupby('Col1',as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g.append(
             pd.DataFrame(data=[['']*len(df.columns)]*num_empty_rows,
                       columns=df.columns))).reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:-num_empty_rows])
```

As you can see, after each group df is appended by a dataframe to accommodate `num_empty_rows` and then at the end reset_index is performed. The last iloc[:-num_empty_rows] is optional i.e. to remove empty rows at the end.

Example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
              'Col2':['s','s','b','b','l'],
              'Col3':['b','j','d','a','k'],
              'Col4':['d','k','q','d','p']
             })
```

Output:

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
0      A       s       b       d
1      A       s       j       k
2      A       b       d       q
3               
4               
5      B       b       a       d
6               
7               
8      C       l       k       p
```