# Adding a blank row after a specific data in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question has been asked for excel. [How to automatically insert a blank row after a group of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417544/how-to-automatically-insert-a-blank-row-after-a-group-of-data). I would like to know if there is a function for doing the same in pandas dataframe.

Comment: Searching this site for how to add empty rows returns several good answers.  Have you tried searching for the answer first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably other (faster?) ways to do this. Here an attempt.

First create a sample dataframe to use for this example. We assume that the index defines the groups that need to be split:

```
users = {'user_id': ['A','A','A','A', 'B','B','B'],
     'status': ['S1', 'S2', 'S1', 'S3', 'S1', 'S2', 'S1'],
     'value': [100, 30, 100, 20, 50, 30, 60 ],
    }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(users, columns = ['user_id', 'status', 'value'])
df1.set_index('user_id', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Here the output:

| user_id | status | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | S1 | 100 |
| **A** | S2 | 30 |
| **A** | S1 | 100 |
| **A** | S3 | 20 |
| **B** | S1 | 50 |
| **B** | S2 | 30 |
| **B** | S1 | 60 |

We create a new dataframe with empty rows, one for each unique element of the index:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index.drop_duplicates(keep='first'))
```

Append the new rows and sort the index:

```
df_merged = df1.append(df2)
df_merged.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

The final output looks as follows:

| user_id | status | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | S1 | 100 |
| **A** | S2 | 30 |
| **A** | S1 | 100 |
| **A** | S3 | 20 |
| **A** | NaN | NaN |
| **B** | S1 | 50 |
| **B** | S2 | 30 |
| **B** | S1 | 60 |
| **B** | NaN | NaN |